# change String in an Arraylist java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to change a String in an Arraylist but having some trouble being able to access the correct position to change.

So I am tried using `students.get(i).getFirstName() = newFirstName;` but I was just really just trying different things at this point.

Below is the code I am trying to make changes for firstName and lastName. This is my `editStudentId` method

```
public void editStudentID(int findStudentId) {

        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (students.get(i).getId() != findStudentId) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Found a profile containing information for " + findStudentId + ":");
            System.out.println("What would you like to change in your profile?");
            System.out.println("1.First Name");
            System.out.println("2.Last Name");
            int decision = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (decision) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter a new first name to continue");
                    String newFirstName = scanner.next();
//so this is the part when I am currently working on but am having some trouble doing so
                    students.get(i).getFirstName() = newFirstName;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter a new last name to continue");


                    break;
            }


           
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(" Id not found ");

    }
```

Here is my class for `Students`

```
public class Student {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String dob;

    public Student(int id,String firstName, String lastName, String dob) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public static Student createStudentID(int id,String firstName, String lastName, String dob)
    {
        return new Student(id,firstName, lastName, dob);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring your strings in the Student class as final if you want to be able to update them?

Comment: oh your right did not see that

Comment: What if your student doesn't have a first name? For most of my life I used by first initial and middle name. I refused to enter any name field where I couldn't put both the first initial and middle name correctly. And what about The Artist that used to be Formerly Known as Prince? He changed his name to an unpronounceable symbol. And those are but two cases, there are many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a set function:

```
public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }
```

Same for the other variables. Setters and Getters are your friends.
Then call these functions. Use `get*` to use the variable, not change. Use `set` to change the variable.

`students.get(i).setFirstName(newFirstName);`